# What is default value of viewBox attribute if omitted from svg?

Tags: html, xml, svg

I think if I omit the `viewBox` attribute from svg it is assumed to be `viewBox="0 0 100 100"`. I tried two tests:

1. With viewBox attribute:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="svg-triangle" width='100' height='100'>
  <path d="M 50,5 95,97.5 5,97.5 z"/>
</svg>
```

2. Without viewBox attribute

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="svg-triangle" width='100' height='100' viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M 50,5 95,97.5 5,97.5 z"/>
</svg>
```

As both the results are same I think my guess is correct. Please give some reference to explain What is default value of viewBox attribute if omitted from svg.

Comment: There is no default value, the display of an svg without a viewBox cannot be replecated by any viewBox value. With a viewBox svg contents will scale with its container, without it won't.

Comment: @RobertLongson Without the `viewBox` tag and without any width or height specified what is the default width and height of svg? I am always getting 300x150 svg.

Comment: Correct, that's the default.

Comment: @RobertLongson I also noticed that with `viewBox` tag the svg takes 100% width of its container even if it's display is `inline`. Why is that?

Comment: Because that's what the SVG spec says should happen. Same as all the other things you've observed.

Comment: @RobertLongson I meant it should have behaved like an inline element takes no width. Inline element has width as much is the content. But I think with svg it's a different story as svg paths don't have widths in pixels.

Comment: It's a replaced element.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't think it's a replaced element, as we can style it's internal parts with css. Even if it is a replaced element what does it have to do with it always behaving as block level? `img` and `input` are also block level but they work `inline` too.

Comment: http://ahmed.amayem.com/html-replaced-elements-non-replaced-elements-examples/#ipt_kb_toc_1785_2 Note item 8

Comment: @RobertLongson That page seems self contradictory. In the just below article _False Objections_ it says _The element itself can be styled using css, but the **content** can’t._ With inline svg we can style the content. I think svg can be called replaced when used in `img` tag `src`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139973/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-user31782).

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not able to find default value in the spec - it seems that is is not defined: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute . Have I missed it somehow?

Comment: @paluh You seem to have missed my very first comment on this question.

Comment: @RobertLongson indeed - sorry!

Answer (score 5):

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute

The default value of an omitted viewbox is "As if not specified."

The problem here is a bit conceptual. So the equivalent viewbox to a non-specified viewbox is `0 0 width height` but an unspecified viewbox simply does not exist. A viewbox is equal to a transform and you often, if rendering this stuff, would make the equivalent transform to a viewbox and add that into your matrix. And unspecified viewbox applies no transformation at all. So this question becomes what is the default value of an unspecified `transform` attribute.

It might help to think of the SVG object itself as an element within Euclidean space, just like the shapes within it. It would be possible for a `circle` object (though not within the spec) to have a viewbox. This would mean it would have a sort of zoom into the coordinate system of the circle and make that zoomed view equal to the size of the circle. So everything that can have a width and height within the space could have a viewbox, and a few of them actually do like image objects and nested SVG objects. Without a viewbox everything is the size that it actually exists within the space. In the case of the SVG object itself this means the viewbox is equal to the view which is equivalent to viewing it at `0 0 width height` since that's the actual size of the object itself. But, really the effect of not having a viewbox is no-effect. Really a viewbox equal to `0 0 width height` will end up applying no scale or translate values when turned into a transform. But, that could have been achieved by simply omitting it.

If the width and height are omitted they are taken to be equal to 100%. Which is to say they take up 100% of the space within the physical box being used to view them. The viewport as opposed to the viewbox.

Comment: Minor point of interest for folks like me dealing with negative x/y positioned values: the default "0 0 width height" here _seems_ to mean chopping off those negative parts of Euclidean space

Comment: My work is more concerned with the actual geometry than the rendering but this is true and depends on the value of overflow. The objects are still there, it's not modifying the data but it does alter whether those parts are rendered or not.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow